# forge viewer mixpanel opt out 7.29

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

> Forge Viewer will start collecting usage analytics not tied to a particular user from version 7.29 onwards for purposes of supporting and improving the Forge Viewer_._ If you do not wish to participate, you may opt-out of this feature using Autodesk.Viewing.Private.analytics.optOut() method.

The above text is taken from: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/#id2

I have ran the above function and I can still see network requests are being sent to mixpanel

[image]

I have tried various ways and cannot get it to work, my latest iteration was to put it in a timeout call to make sure AutoDesk has been loaded but still it tries to send requests to mixpanel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(() => {
            debugger;
            if (typeof window.Autodesk == 'undefined') {
                console.log('no auto desk yet');
            } else {
                console.log('auto is ready');
                window.Autodesk.Viewing.Private.analytics.optOut();
            }
        }, 500);
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {});
    </script>
```

debugging I can step into the else block and also see a console log that says "auto is ready".

How do you disable mixpanel?

Answer (score 0):

When `.optOut()` is called the Viewer will not collect any data.

After opting out whenever you load the page, the Mixpanel library makes a single decision call which results in a simple yes or no response (opt-out status), and no user tracking data is sent. We’ll investigate how we can avoid even making the decision call during the model load and get back to you with more information.

Comment: if the user has an ad/tracker blocker installed the mixpanel shows up as an error in the console. Would be good to turn off completely.

Comment: @Phil thanks for the information, we'll definitely check how to improve.